# How to write a function with a variable to be defined on later code

Tags: python

I am making a function on python3 that solves ax^2+bx+c so a quadratic equation

My code looks like this:

```
def quadratic(a, b, c):
    return a*x**2 + b*x + c
```

But it wont let me do this because x is undefined. I want to take the argument x on a test code
that looks like this:

```
def testQuadratic(a, b, c, x):
    try:
        return quadratic(a, b, c)(x)
    except TypeError:
        return None
```

Can anyone tell me how I can fix this?
Thank you!!

Answer (score 7):

You can make use of the fact that Python supports first-class functions, that can be passed into and returned from other functions.

```py
def make_quadratic(a, b, c):
    def f(x):
        return a*(x**2) + b*x + c
    return f

# You would call the returned function
my_quadratic = make_quadratic(a, b, c)

# You can then call my_quadratic(x) as you would elsewhere
```

Answer (score 3):

Your quadratic function should... **return a function**!

```py
def quadratic(a, b, c):
  def calculate_quadratic(x):
    return a*x**2 + b*x + c
  return calculate_quadratic
```

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear whether you intend 'solve' to mean

1. find a root of the quadratic equation, or
2. produce an output for a given value of `x`

Since you're taking `x` as an input argument, I'll assume the second option (snatchysquid gave an answer for the first option):

```
def quadratic(a, b, c):
    return a*x**2 + b*x + c

def testQuadratic(a, b, c, x):
    try:
        return quadratic(a, b, c, x)
    except TypeError:
        return None
```

of course unless you need `def quadratic` for some other reason, then it would be simpler to use:

```
def testQuadratic(a, b, c, x):
    try:
        return a*x**2 + b*x + c
    except TypeError:
        return None
```

You still might want to handle other errors besides `TypeError`.

Comment: Your code does still give the NameError?

Answer (score 0):

You can read about quadratic equations [here](https://www.mathsisfun.com/quadratic-equation-solver.html) and in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation).

There is a formula for solving quadratic equations so you can use this code:

```
import math

def quadratic_equation(a, b, c):
    """
    :params a,b,c: the coefficients of the equation ax^2+bx+c=0
    :return: a tuple (of len 2) with the solutions to the equation
    :rtype: tuple
    """

    discriminant = b ** 2 - (4 * a * c)
    if discriminant < 0:
        return None, None
    if discriminant == 0:
        return -b / (2 * a), None
    return (-b + math.sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a), (-b - math.sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a)
```

The reason your code doesn't work is that python does not understand "missing variables", and thinks that `x` is some defined variable, for example `x = 2`, but you use the math notation which python does not understand.

Comment: Can you refer to where you get this code from?

Comment: @Austin I wrote it like a few months ago, I keep all my codes in a folder on my pc.

Comment: @Austin You can take a look [here for reference](https://www.tutorialgateway.org/python-program-to-find-roots-of-a-quadratic-equation/) or [here](https://progbook.org/ex_quad2.html)